# RxJs : 'Map' on an Array of Observable<T>, but returning as soon as a T match a condition

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

Context : Application written with Angular2 in TypeScript, + rxjs 5.

Edit : I'm precising that I am relatively new to the Rx library and the way things should be done "the idiomatic way". And yes, I tried to find some clues in the documentation before posting on SO.

I have this :

```
class Result { constructor(public inError: boolean) { } }

const checks : Array<() => Observable<Result>> = [...];
```

This is an array of functions, each function returning an observable that will contains a Result object.

What I want :

- I want to 'map' this array into an `Array<Observable<Result>>`,
  basically by calling each function in turn ...
- ... but I want to break the 'map' as soon as the first `Result.inError` is true !

I'm desesperalty stuck, fiddling with `reduce`, `takeWith`, `contains`, etc...
The deferred nature of the Observables are puzzling me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: And maybe the downvoter could explain why he downvoted my question ?

Answer (score 0):

If your observables are performing a synchronous operations, you can simply do this:

```
const results = [];
for (const i = 0; i < checks.length; i +=1) {
    checks[i]().subscribe(result => if (result.inError) {
        break;
    } else {
        results.push(checks[i]());
    });
}
// Results observables accessible here.
```

In the asynchronous observers case:

```
const results = [];
function callObservable(index) {
    checks[index]().subscribe(result => if (result.inError) {
            // Results observables accessible here.
        } else {
            results.push(checks[i]());
            callObservable(index + 1);
        })
}
callObservable(0);
```

Doing any of that doesn't give any benefits, though. Your observables are already called, before they even reach the results array, or will have another value, if called from this array again.

Answer (score 0):

After more and more digging, here is a solution :

```
// Some class that will be contained in my observables
class Result { constructor(public inError: boolean) { } }

// An array of Observables that will emit those classes instances
// the thunk is just here to lazy instantiate the Result classes
// only when needed
const oResults : Array<() => Observable<Result>> = [
  Rx.Observable.of(() => new Result(false)),
  Rx.Observable.of(() => new Result(false)),
  Rx.Observable.of(() => new Result(true)),
  Rx.Observable.of(() => new Result(false))
];

// An home made (found on SO) INCLUSIVE 'takeWhile' version
const takeWhileInclusive(source, predicate){
    return source.publish(co => co.takeWhile(predicate)
        .merge(co.skipWhile(predicate).take(1)));
}

// Let's filter out things as expected
const res = takeWhileInclusive(
    Rx.Observable.merge(oResults).map( x => x()), 
    x => !x.inError
);

// I can now subscribe to the resulting stream and will only get
// all the first Results that are false AND the first following result that
// is true
res.subscribe(next => console.info("Next result", next));
```